Complex review how much context?
I have some code that needs reviewing based on the C++ Co-Routines that were released with C++20.
This is a non trivial update to the language (I am not sure I understand it). If I just put the code in for review I don't believe I would get any meaningful comments. So I want to provide a lot of context and explanation to go with the code (a lot more explanation than code). Hence this question to see if that is OK.
The sections I want to include:

A description of the overall problem (and how it currently works (boost)).
A simplified bit of code that simulates the environment (I actually used this to create the code).
An explanation of how I think Co-Routines work (because this matters in the implementation).
The code to actually review.
How that changes the simulation environment to plug it in.

Note the code for review works in both the real and simulated environments the real environment is just way to large to include for a code review.

More context is usually better. Not everyone will read a wall of text, but with the kind of questions you pose you'll prefer reviewers who don't shy away from that anyway. What are you concerned about?

@Mast: Eventually I want to turn what I have learned into a Blog. Getting the code reviewed / fixed / spruced up, is part of that processes. I don't want others to feel like I am abusing the site by doing this.

Licensing wise you should be fine as long as you comply with the CC BY-SA the content is provided under. Based on what you shared here, I don't see any problems on the horizon.

How people are going to feel in general, is very hard to gauge.

Personally I wouldn't assume the #4 user on our site is abusing the site. I'm not really sure what you'd like us to answer with. I feel you already know about zombie ratings, and the answer I'd post is duplicate to your last question.

Sounds like a good outline to me.  I'm not sure what you mean by "simulating the environment", but if it's anything like a programming-challenge or interview-question, then it sounds like the kind of context that's well-received here.  Certainly, an explanation of the operation of your code is very useful, as it can help reviewers identify any discrepancies compared to the actual behaviour.
